# C# ASP.NET MySql Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
                try
            {
                conn.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE `users` SET `firstname`=@firstname,`lastname`=@lastname,`industry`=@industry,`companyname`=@companyname,`country`=@country,`addressone`=@addressone,`addresstwo`=@addresstwo,`city`=@city,`stateOrProvince`=@stateone,`zip`=@zip,`phone`=@phone,`companyphone`=@companyphone,`countrytwo`=@countrytwo,`citytwo`=@citytwo,`statetwo`=@statetwo,`ziptwo`=@ziptwo WHERE `email`=@email", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@industry", dropDownIndustry.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyname", companyInfo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", countryTextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressone", addressInfo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addresstwo", addresstwoInfo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", cityTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateone", stateTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", zipTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", newphone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyphone", phonecompany);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countrytwo", countryTextBoxtwo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@citytwo", cityTwoTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statetwo", stateTwoTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["email"]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                serverErrorTextBox.Text = "Data updated Successfully...!" + companyPhoneTextBox.Text + " " + Session["email"] + "";
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                serverErrorTextBox.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
```

I can't quite figure out what is wrong with this query can someone please help I'm using this to update user info as a first time script all the help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Don't use `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: post the error here

Comment: Do you get an exception or is this just outputting the wrong data? Please clarify what the current result is when you try to execute this code, and what you expected it to be.

Comment: maybe you changed datatype of columns or something deleted from table?
show here please full error message

Comment: without more information or clarity we could give you a bunch of answers which are all legit but wont solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not have ziptwo param!! which is in your update statement

Comment: It seems that this has fixed my problem thanks! (: I feel dumb now though. I went and changed it to a using statement instead of a try statement and it output that I did not have a ziptwo ahahahaha wish I would have noticed this I would have not gone through such a big struggle. Guess I shouldn't attempt to do things when I'm so tired xD

Answer (score -1):

```
try
        {
            conn.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE `users` SET `firstname`=@firstname,`lastname`=@lastname,`industry`=@industry,`companyname`=@companyname,`country`=@country,`addressone`=@addressone,`addresstwo`=@addresstwo,`city`=@city,`stateOrProvince`=@stateone,`zip`=@zip,`phone`=@phone,`companyphone`=@companyphone,`countrytwo`=@countrytwo,`citytwo`=@citytwo,`statetwo`=@statetwo,`ziptwo`=@ziptwo WHERE `email`=@email", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = firstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastname",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@industry",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dropDownIndustry.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyname",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = companyInfo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@country",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = countryTextbox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@addressone",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = addressInfo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@addresstwo",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = addresstwoInfo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@city",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cityTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@stateone",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = stateTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@zip",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = zipTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newphone);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@companyphone",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = phonecompany);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@countrytwo",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = countryTextBoxtwo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@citytwo",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cityTwoTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statetwo",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = stateTwoTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["email"]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            serverErrorTextBox.Text = "Data updated Successfully...!" + companyPhoneTextBox.Text + " " + Session["email"] + "";
        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            serverErrorTextBox.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: If you're going to go to the trouble of answering a question, at least write what you have changed.

Comment: So is there a reason you added SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value to the cmd.Parameters.Add statements. if there is a proper reasoning for this as in security issues please do let me know thanks.